# <select> population not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a jquery script that populates a second `<select>` according to the selection made on the first `<select>`. Everything works fine but of course I have problems with Internet Explorer and I don't know how to solve it.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        var categories = [
            {
               value: '1',
               name: 'Telefoane, Tablete si Laptopuri',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '10',
                   name: 'Telefoane Mobile'
               }, {
                   value: '11',
                   name: 'Tablete'
               }, {
                   value: '12',
                   name: 'Laptopuri'
               }, {
                   value: '13',
                   name: 'Smartwatch'
               }, {
                   value: '14',
                   name: 'Bratari Fitness'
               }, {
                   value: '15',
                   name: 'Drone'
               }, {
                   value: '16',
                   name: 'Altele'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '2',
               name: 'PC, Componente si Periferice',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '17',
                   name: 'Sisteme PC'
               }, {
                   value: '18',
                   name: 'Monitoare'
               }, {
                   value: '19',
                   name: 'Componente PC'
               }, {
                   value: '20',
                   name: 'Periferice PC'
               }, {
                   value: '21',
                   name: 'Imprimante si Consumabile'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '3',
               name: 'TV, Audio, Foto si Gaming',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '22',
                   name: 'Televizoare'
               }, {
                   value: '23',
                   name: 'Home Cinema si Audio'
               }, {
                   value: '24',
                   name: 'Aparate Foto si Accesorii'
               }, {
                   value: '25',
                   name: 'Camere Video si Sport'
               }, {
                   value: '26',
                   name: 'Console si Jocuri'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '4',
               name: 'Electrocasnice',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '27',
                   name: 'Aer conditionat'
               }, {
                   value: '28',
                   name: 'Frigorifice'
               }, {
                   value: '29',
                   name: 'Masini de spalat rufe'
               }, {
                   value: '30',
                   name: 'Aragazuri'
               }, {
                   value: '31',
                   name: 'Hote'
               }, {
                   value: '32',
                   name: 'Masini de spalat vase'
               }, {
                   value: '33',
                   name: 'Cuptoare cu microunde'
               }, {
                   value: '34',
                   name: 'Aparate de bucatarie'
               }, {
                   value: '35',
                   name: 'Aparate de calcat'
               }, {
                   value: '36',
                   name: 'Aspiratoare'
               }, {
                   value: '37',
                   name: 'Altele'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '5',
               name: 'Casa, Gradina si Bricolaj',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '38',
                   name: 'Mobila si Decoratiuni'
               }, {
                   value: '39',
                   name: 'Gradina'
               }, {
                   value: '40',
                   name: 'Materiale de constructii'
               }, {
                   value: '41',
                   name: 'Termice'
               }, {
                   value: '42',
                   name: 'Electrice si Sanitare'
               }, {
                   value: '43',
                   name: 'Unelte'
               }, {
                   value: '44',
                   name: 'Scule si Feronerie'
               }, {
                   value: '45',
                   name: 'Articole menaj'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '6',
               name: 'Sport si Activitati',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '46',
                   name: 'Alergare'
               }, {
                   value: '47',
                   name: 'Atletism si Triatlon'
               }, {
                   value: '48',
                   name: 'Sporturi de iarna'
               }, {
                   value: '49',
                   name: 'Ciclism'
               }, {
                   value: '50',
                   name: 'Drumetii'
               }, {
                   value: '51',
                   name: 'Camping si Articole voiaj'
               }, {
                   value: '52',
                   name: 'Tenis si Tenis de masa'
               }, {
                   value: '53',
                   name: 'Role'
               }, {
                   value: '54',
                   name: 'Trotinete si Skateboard'
               }, {
                   value: '55',
                   name: 'Pescuit si Vanatoare'
               }, {
                   value: '56',
                   name: 'Altele'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '7',
               name: 'Auto si Moto',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '57',
                   name: 'Anvelope si Jante'
               }, {
                   value: '58',
                   name: 'Intretinere si Cosmetica auto'
               }, {
                   value: '59',
                   name: 'Electronice auto'
               }, {
                   value: '60',
                   name: 'Accesorii auto'
               }, {
                   value: '61',
                   name: 'Moto'
               }, {
                   value: '62',
                   name: 'ATV'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '8',
               name: 'Jucarii, Copii si Bebe',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '63',
                   name: 'Scutece si Hrana'
               }, {
                   value: '64',
                   name: 'Igiena si Ingrijire'
               }, {
                   value: '65',
                   name: 'Carucioare'
               }, {
                   value: '66',
                   name: 'Imbracaminte'
               }, {
                   value: '67',
                   name: 'Jucarii'
               }]
            }, {
               value: '9',
               name: 'Animale de companie',
               subCategories: [{
                   value: '68',
                   name: 'Caini'
               }, {
                   value: '69',
                   name: 'Pisici'
               }, {
                   value: '70',
                   name: 'Hrana'
               }, {
                   value: '71',
                   name: 'Lese si Zgarzi'
               }, {
                   value: '72',
                   name: 'Jucarii'
               }, {
                   value: '73',
                   name: 'Imbracaminte'
               }, {
                   value: '74',
                   name: 'Altele'
               }]
            }
        ];

        var $categorySelect =  $("#category");
        var $subCategorySelect =  $("#subcategory");

        // populate categories with options
        categories.forEach(function(category) {
            var $option = $('<option/>').attr('value', category.value).html(category.name);
            $categorySelect.append($option);
        });

        $categorySelect.on('change', function() {
            // clean subcategory select from older options
            $subCategorySelect.empty();

            // find selected category
            var selectedCategoryValue = $categorySelect.val();
            var category = categories.find(function(category) {
                return category.value == selectedCategoryValue;
            });

            // if category found - populate subcategory select
            if (category) {
                category.subCategories.forEach(function(subcategory) {

                    // you can extract this line into separate function
                    var $option = $('<option/>').attr('value', subcategory.value).html(subcategory.name);

                    $subCategorySelect.append($option);
                });
            }

        })

});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="step">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Categorie</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                    <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subcategorie</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Someone can help me with this situation?

PS: Please ask if you need any other info from me.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eh437hL2/#

Comment: which version of IE? Dont use forEach.use $each of jquery.

Comment: I was testing in IE11 when I discovered that this isn't working

Comment: what errors do you have in the console?

Comment: @AndreiRăileanu please set up a fiddle/plnkr.

Comment: @Madalin Ivascu SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eh437hL2/#

Comment: @AndreiRăileanu see answer I have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter instead of find, find is used for dom traversal,filter is used for
 filtering values

```
var category = categories.filter(function(category) {
                return category.value == selectedCategoryValue;
            });
if (category[0]) {
            category[0].subCategories.forEach(function(subcategory) {

                // you can extract this line into separate function
                var $option = $('<option/>').attr('value', subcategory.value).html(subcategory.name);

                $subCategorySelect.append($option);
            });
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2xyuerdr/

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kxygyk7/) and it works in IE11.

so the codes re written as looks like below.

```
$.each(categories, function(k, v)
         { 
          $('#category').append($('<option>', { 
            value: v.value,
            text : v.name 
           }));              
         });

         $('#category').on('change', function() {
                 alert('selected value '+this.value); 
                 var val = this.value;
                 var result = categories.filter(function(v) {
                 return v.value === val; 
                  })[0].subCategories;                 
                console.log(result);

           $.each(result, function(ka, va)
           {
              $('#subcategory').append($('<option>', { 
                 value: va.value,
                 text : va.name 
              }));              
           });             
         });
```

### Key Points

- Don't use `forEach` as Jquery has `.each()` to iterate the objects.
- Don't use redundant selectors.$ is powerful enough.
- Use `filter` to filter out objects matching criteria.
- Dropdown (select) has text and value property.Not html.